# Odoo12 Many2many computed field is not triggering fuction

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I added a Many2many field to 'purchase.order' related to 'account.invoice'.

In between these 2 models, there is another model called 'work.acceptance'.
**'purchase.order'** creates a record in **'work.acceptance'** and then, when creating a record in **'account.invoice'**, you can choose a *'work.acceptance'* record to make the relation.

In **purchase.order** I added a Many2many field related to **'account.invoice'**. This field is computed. So I have this:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError
import time
import datetime


class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    invoice_ids = fields.Many2many('account.invoice', compute='compute_invs', 
    string='Invoices')

    @api.multi
    def compute_invs(self):
        print('Function triggered.')
        for oc in self:
            if oc.id:
                domain = [('work_acceptance.purchase_id.id', '=', oc.id)]
                print(domain)
                invoices = self.env['account.invoice'].search(domain)
                oc.update({'invoice_ids': invoices})
```

I don't know what's the problem, but the function is not being triggered (because nothing is printed in console). And it's weird because I have done this logig with May2many fields a few times befores and they worked well.

Comment: Simple question : Are your sure the field named work_acceptance is existing in class PurchaseOrder ?

Comment: Did you add this field to your form and/or list view? If so, what happens if you try to manually insert a record?